# Idle's Code Context in Eclipse

Tags: python, eclipse, pydev

I find the Code Context option of IDLE to be extremely useful when working on big projects.
I wanted to know if there is a similar feature for Eclipse?

Edit:
I would like this feature in CDT and/or PyDev.

Example image:
http://i38.tinypic.com/95sb39.jpg

Comment: I'm assuming you are asking specifically for Python with PyDev. For Java, there's a feature called "Breadcrumbs" which looks about the same.

Comment: Yeah, Python and C are my main programming languages.

Answer (score 0):

[Breadcrump](http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/reference/ref-java-editor-breadcrumb.htm) feature can help you determine your current context.

Comment: As stated above, that is only relevant for Java. I would like something for Pydev and/or CDT.

Answer (score 0):

That's still not available for PyDev... for now you can either use the outline view and leave it synchronized with the editor or you can use the quick outline (ctrl+O) as it'll focus which method you're in (I know it's not really a substitute, but until the the 'breadcrumb' feature is not added, that's probably the best way to know where you are).

Note that this is for PyDev 2.2.1 (please keep an eye on the upcoming releases as this feature is close to being implemented).